# how to differentiate in code between Sangunio and Microduino core+

Tags: hardware

**Sanguino** and **Microduino** core+ both uses **`ATMEGA644PA`**. I need to write a piece of code in my library where I need to check what board has been selected.

```cpp
#elif defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
#   define TIMER_PWM_PIN  11             // Arduino Mega
#elif defined(__AVR_ATmega644P__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega644__)// Sanguino or microduino
#    define TIMER_PWM_PIN  13        //Sanguino PD5
#elif defined(__AVR_ATtiny84__)
# define TIMER_PWM_PIN  6
#else
#   define TIMER_PWM_PIN  9              // Arduino Duemilanove, Diecimila, LilyPad, etc
#endif
```

If I used the above code `#elif defined(__AVR_ATmega644P__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega644__)// Sanguino or Microduino` will be true for both Microduino and Sanguino.

Is there a way I can know which one is it?

Here is the board.txt section for Microduino core +

```cpp
##Microduino Core+ (644pa)
##############################################################
644p.name= Microduino/mCookie-Core+ (644pa)

644p.upload.tool=avrdude
644p.upload.protocol=arduino

644p.bootloader.tool=avrdude
644p.bootloader.unlock_bits=0x3F
644p.bootloader.lock_bits=0x0F

644p.build.board=AVR_PLUS
644p.build.core=arduino
644p.build.variant=plus
```

Comment: Never heard of either of them. Do they have specific Arduino IDE configurations for them? Do those configurations define a `_BOARD_xxxx_` macro you can examine?

Comment: I ll check that !

Comment: Where should they be?

Comment: In a file called boards.txt somewhere wherever the boards were installed to by the IDE.

Comment: Ok and how should that appear?

Comment: As a file. Called boards.txt. What more do you want? It has text in it. Key/value pairs. In groups for the different boards.

Comment: I mean which key:value pair will define that? is it the variant? or board?

Comment: I have no idea in the current version. It used to be board.define IIRC in older versions.